# Get detail days between two date (mysql query)

Tags: sql, date, mariadb

I have data like this:

```
id | start_date | end_date
----------------------------
1  | 16-09-2019 | 22-12-2019
```

I want to get the following results:

```
id | month | year | days
------------------------
1  | 09    | 2019 | 15
1  | 10    | 2019 | 31
1  | 11    | 2019 | 30
1  | 12    | 2019 | 22
```

Is there a way to get that result ?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: 5.5.5-10.4.7-MariaDB-1:10.4.7

Comment: I assume the "16" for September is a typo.  September has 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
SELECT id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date ) as month , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date ) as year , DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date ) as days
From tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MONTH()` , `YEAR()` and `DATEDIFF()` functions

```
SELECT id, MONTH(start_date) as month, YEAR(start_date ) as year,  DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date ) as days from table-name
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a `Calendar` table and use that.

```
select month,year, count(*)
from Calendar
where db_date between '2019-09-16'
              and '2019-12-22' 
group by month,year
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e7eae864cb34c65903ae9dd2fa8018a4)

Also you can use `recursive CTE` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE and aggregation:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, start_date, end_date
      from t
      union all
      select id, start_date + interval 1 day, end_date
      from cte
      where start_date < end_date
     )
select id, year(start_date), month(start_date), count(*) as days
from cte
group by id, year(start_date), month(start_date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d295758a689febd07c3d6927b3ef71c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this works even if dates are not in the date format?

Comment: @LelioFaieta . . . No, but you should fix the data so your dates are stored correctly.  In the mean time, you can convert the strings to dates.

Comment: I’m asking since op’s dates are strings and not dates if I’m not wrong

Comment: @LelioFaieta . . . There is no reason to assume that the columns are not dates.  People write dates in many formats and the OP has not specified the type.  Given the names of the columns and the data, it is quite reasonable to assume the best -- that the columns are stored correctly.

Comment: Imho you should include this assumption in the answer since the standard date format is yyyy-mm-dd and to change this requires a specific setup

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but when I try to apply it in my data, the results that come out are different.

Comment: @nsag . . . There is a db<>fiddle that shows that this code works.

Comment: yes, that is absolutely right. but Idk why, the last data is always added 1 day. which should be => 1 | 12 | 2019 | 22
but instead it became => 1 | 12 | 2019 | 23

Comment: @nsag . . . The value in the db<>fiddle is "22" not "23".